Drupal with kubernetes using archives yaml
I'm traying to install drupal using kubernetes.
I created the cluster, and the deployments, and it's work, but when I access using localhost:8085 and I started to install I have the following errors:
-"The default settings file does not exist.
The Drupal installer requires that the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file must not be deleted or modified from the original download."
-"The Settings file does not exist.
The Drupal installer requires that you create a ./sites/default/settings.php as part of the installation process. Copy the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file to ./sites/default/settings.php. More details about installing Drupal are available in INSTALL.txt."
I think is about the initContainer.
So the default.settings.php is not been copy to settings.php in my yaml archive that is the following:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: drupal-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: drupal
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: drupal

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: drupal
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drupal
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: drupal
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-sites
          image: busybox
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -r /var/www/html/sites/default/default.settings.php /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php']
          volumeMounts:
            - name: drupal-sites-volume
              mountPath: /var/www/html/sites

      containers:
        - image: drupal:latest
          name: drupal
          env:
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_HOST
              value: mysql
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_NAME
              value: drupal
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_USER
              value: drupal
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_PASSWORD
              value: drupalpassword
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: drupal-sites-volume
              mountPath: /var/www/html/sites
      volumes:
        - name: drupal-sites-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: drupal-pv-claim
`

I tried many command but I don't know how to do it. Please help.

I checked if the drupal base image have the default.settings.php and it have it.


The various things that mention volumes will most likely have the effect of overwriting your sites directory with an empty directory.  Is that directory built into the image?  If so, deleting all mentions of any sort of volume should help.  You can also RUN cp ... in your image's Dockerfile to put the right config file in place, and remove the initContainers:.

Thanks, but I need to use initContainers: tag, the pod logs is always:
cp: can't stat '/var/www/html/sites/default/default.settings.php': No such file or directory

As you have it set up, the init container is trying to copy a file from one place to another, within the (empty) mounted volume.
